# Solve the recursion $a_{n+1} = a_n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) +1; a_1=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

Solve the recursion $a_{n+1} = a_n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) +1; a_1=1$

Can this recursion be solved? I don't think generating functions would help. I tried converting it to a telescoping series as well and ended up with 
$$a_{n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left\{a_k \left( \frac{1}{k} \right)\right\} + (n+1)$$

A bit of observations gave me a hint that $\exists n$ such that $a_n > x ~ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Is that something correct? I am not sure but can that be proven? (using bounding?)

Comment: The recursion is $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{a_n}n+\frac1{n+1}$$ with the initial condition $$\frac{a_1}1=1$$ hence $$\frac{a_n}n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$ that is, $$a_n=n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$

Comment: @Did You must not use the comment section to post answer. It seems to be a norm for some ( I say 'some' ) high reputation users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ n a_{n+1} = a_n (n+1) + n \tag{1}$$
can be rearranged as
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{a_n}{n} = \frac{1}{n+1}\tag{2} $$
hence by summing both sides of $(2)$ over $n\in[1,N]$ we get
$$ \frac{a_{N+1}}{N+1}-1 = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{N+1} = H_{N+1}-1 \tag{3} $$
then
$$ a_N = N H_N = N\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k}.\tag{4} $$

Comment: Fine, so the second part of the question (which can be reframed as $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = +\infty$) follows from here as the harmonic series diverges. Got you, thanks!

Comment: @mathwizard1 The divergence of the harmonic sequence $(H_n)$ is not a requisite for the divergence of $(a_n)$, which simply follows from the direct lower bound $a_n\geqslant n$.